# How to access data from a scope with a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, People and Vehicles.  I created a scope that shows which people do not have Vehicles.

`scope :person_has_no_vehicle, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.person_id = people.id").where('Vehicles.person_id IS NULL').limit(100)}`

In my View I have

`<% @person.person_has_no_vehicle.each do |test| %>`

How would I access data from my vehicles table?

I.E.

`<% if test.vehicles.person_id == NIL %>`  <-- That does not work, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you some refactor:

```
# FROM
scope :person_has_no_vehicle, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.person_id = people.id").where('Vehicles.person_id IS NULL').limit(100)}
# TO
scope :without_vehicle, -> { includes(:vehicles).where(vehicles: { id: nil }).limit(100) }
```

Then in your view you can use:

```
<% People.without_vehicle.each do |people| %>
  # These People instances do not have any vehicle record associated
  # so `people.vehicles` in this loop should return an empty ActiveRecord::Relation
```

---

I don't understand why you "would access data from the vehicles table", the scope you want is the exact opposite: People without any vehicle associated.

Anyway, if you really want to test if there is not Vehicle corresponding to the People record, try this:

```
<% People.without_vehicle.each do |people| %>
  <%= "THIS GUY OWNS AT LEAST 1 VEHICLE!!" if people.vehicles.present? %>
```

Comment: Im wanting to access data from the vehicles table for testing purposes.  Essentially to double check that vehicles.person_id is null.

Comment: This is great refactoring, but I still cannot access data in that vehicles table.

Comment: Also sometimes with the data imports it brings in information about a vehicle but does not give it a person_id.

Comment: It is perfectly normal that every people returned by the scope has no vehicle. I'll add a piece of code to test it but you don't have to. About your data imports, I will need more informations (how you import your data, etc).

Comment: Ahhh I see now.  I changed it to `<% if people.vehicles.present? != NIL %>

       NULL

       <% end %>`

Comment: If you want to test if something is `nil`, **don't use** `your_object != NIL` but `your_object.nil?`